# /etc/network/interfaces file empty

Tags: wireless, networking

I don't know what I did but my network manager doesn't start up and my wifi doesn't work unless I do it all manually.  I've read that I need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces` file but when I look for it, only the `interfaces.bak` file exists.

So I type `sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces` and it opens but it's blank.  Is this why my internet is all screwy? And how can I fix it? I also get a bunch of `ndiswrapper` errors on boot and it takes forever trying to set up the network configuration which it never does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `/etc/network/interfaces` file just got renamed. Try moving it back:

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces.bak /etc/network/interfaces
sudo reboot
```